# Python: str.split() with whitespace gives Index Error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to check the validity of the Phone Numbers in a dataframe.

In particular, I want to check whether a Phone Number contains whitespaces:
- If YES and the first part is longer than 6 characters, I want to delete the second part; if it's not 6 characters long, I want to delete the whitespace
- If NO, continue

This is my code:

```
print(np.where(
    offline.PHONE_NUMBER.notnull(), 
        np.where(offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.contains(" ", regex = False),
            np.where(offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.split(expand = True)[1] != 'None',
                     np.where(offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.split(expand = True)[0].str.contains(r".{6,}", regex = True),
             offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.split(expand = True)[0], offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.replace(r" ", "")), 
                     offline.PHONE_NUMBER), offline.PHONE_NUMBER), offline.PHONE_NUMBER))
```

and it gives my IndexError: list index out of range.

I know from previous questions that str.split() could give error if the expected character is not contained in the string, but I thought that with the check on null values and offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.contains(" ", regex = False) I could avoid this problem.

Can you help me? What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code is trying to do too much in one line. Have you tried figuring out exactly which part of your code is causing the error?

Comment: Yes, it's this one: np.where(offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.split(expand = True)[1] != 'None', when I try to apply for the first time the str.split() function

Answer (score 2):

Is it giving the error on line 4? It could be due to trailing whitespace - 123456_ would not split into two, but one. Try using python's built in .strip() method to remove leading and trailing whitespace first.

Comment: Yes, the error it's on line 4. Thank you, but unfortunately it's giving me the same error even with .strip() method

Answer (score 0):

Index out of range from split() means you're trying to access something that wasn't splitted. Instead of:

```
offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.split(expand = True)[1] != 'None'
```

try something like:

```
len(offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.split(expand = True))>1
```

Now why it's not doing the split? We need to see the data.

Comment: Using the filter on `len(offline.PHONE_NUMBER.str.split(expand = True))>1` it works, thank you!